# Inserting boolean value into MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm attempting to insert some values into a MySQL table, the first 2 values being string and the last being a boolean value. My problem is that I no matter what I do I can't seem to make python/MySQL recognize the boolean as such and insert it. From what I can tell Python is correctly making the last value a boolean, but MySQL isn't seeing it as such. Each time it just defaults to 0 in the table. Below is some pseudo code that is pretty much what I'm trying to do.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO table (name, string, bool) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,(aName,aString,boolVal))
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html).  A "Boolean" datatype will just be 0 or 1.

The behavior you're seeing is expected.

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.7 and MySQLdb package it works for me in this way.

1. For columns of varchar type use `'%s'`
2. For or boolean, number use just `%s`, `%d`, `%i`.

```sql
INSERT INTO table (string, bool) VALUES ('%s',%s) % ('string',True)`
```

Answer (score 2):

if the value is True or False
in python you can use int()

```
>>> a = True
>>> int(a)
1
>>>

conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO table (bool) VALUES (%s)",( int(boolVal),))
```